# Ways to handle concurrent stl-container expansions efficiently

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl

I have this cute little problem that I have an STL container (unordered_map, or vector) that may both be read and expanded by any number of threads, and I want to do it as efficiently as possible (i. e. reduce the lock latency by as much as possible).

Now, the easy part is to use a shared lock for reading and an exclusive lock for extending, so I might be doing something like this:

```
boost::shared_lock myLock;
std::unordered_map myMap;

...

myLock.lock_shared();
//try looking up key
myLock.unlock_shared();
if(!success) {
    myLock.lock();
    //retry looking up key
    if(!success) {
        myMap[key] = value;
    }
    myLock.unlock();
}
```

While I believe this to be rather efficient in the general case, the time the exclusive lock is held may explode if `myMap` decides that it needs to reallocate its internal storage. The time that lock is held might go up to several hundred microseconds, and it will block any thread that attempts to read the container during this time.

Does anybody know of an idiom that can be used to avoid blocking all reading threads while the storage is reallocated?

Of course, I know the math that tells me that these latencies will not accumulate to bring down overall performance, nevertheless I would be happier if I could limit the possible latencies somehow.

Comment: You'd probably want a container that was developed with concurrent access in mind, so it would incorporate appropriate locking at only the critical points during the expansion (e.g. it could allocate the new storage and do the copying outside the lock, then just lock for the swap-in). I don't believe the STL/Boost ones work that way - hence your current coarse-grained locking approach. There might be other libraries out there that already work this way, or you might have to roll your own...

Comment: Maybe it would be good to use `try_lock_shared()` in the reading threads, so that they don't get blocked trying to acquire the lock.  Of course that assumes that they can do something else when they can't get the lock.

Answer (score 0):

I can see two possible solutions here. But they may be incompatible with other logic of your program.

**1)** You can preallocate once (or more rarely than STL does it) enough number of container's elements with `vector::reserve()`/`unordered_map.reserve()`. If that is suitable for your program then you will avoid further container reallocations or lower their number.

**2)** You can use the copy-modify-swap approach. It may increase the number of memory allocations and copyings greatly but will also decrease greatly the time when threads are blocked.

The code would be something like this:

```
atomic<unordered_map*> pmyMap;

void ChangeMap(){
  unordered_map* pOldMap = pmyMap.load();
  unordered_map* pNewMap = 0;
  {
    if (pNewMap != 0) delete pNewMap;
    pNewMap = new std::unordered_map(*pOldMap); // copy
    (*pNewMap)[key] = value; // modify the copy
  }
  while (!pmyMap.compare_exchange_weak(pOldMap, pNewMap)) // swap
}
```

In that case you can read from the container without the locks at all.
The main problem here is to delete old copy of the container correctly. You can't delete it simply at the end of `ChangeMap()` because other thread can read from it (e.g. iterate it) at the same time. To delete the old container correctly you have to track the reading threads in some way and delete the container object only when all reads are finished.

Comment: I have already thought about both variants. Problem with `reserve()` is that I would still have to do an exclusive lock while `reserve()` is called, and I do not have an upper bound on the containers size. And copy-modify-swap is expensive to do for every insertion if the containers are large. Nevertheless, I'm still ransacking my brain for a variant of those methods that would fit my needs...

Comment: @cmaster If your main concern is the blocking time when a container is being relocated then may be you need a container that doesn't relocate memory when growing at all? Something like singly- or doubly-linked list (std::list, std::forward_list)? Of course such containers will increase search time but the problem with relocations will disappear. Or may be std::map/std::set? I may be wrong but AFAIK they don't relocate memory when growing too.

Comment: @Alex_Antonov: As I have said in the comment to MarkB, both performance (of lookup) and maximal latency are a concern to me. And while solving one is easy, having only one just won't cut it...

Answer (score 0):

Intel's TBB library is very good.  I've used concurrent_hash_map.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately, I can't find anything in the documentation saying whether `concurrent_hash_map` blocks all reading threads while reallocating the storage. Do you know how they do that internally? Another point is that I need to handle objects that are immutable, thus no locking on the objects is necessary. Yet, the `concurrent_hash_map` does locking through the accessors, which implies overhead I would like to avoid.

Comment: From my understanding of the implementation, they use a RW semaphore.  I'm not sure why you believe immutable objects changes the concurrency requirements since container objects don't care what you're storing in them.  If you truly have unbounded container size, RW semaphores are the most efficient choice (reads are unblocked, provided nobody is writing).  Also, have you measured the performance of the code?  The overhead of locking is minimal...it's typically the application causing contention for locks that is the bottleneck.

Comment: I know that RW locks are quite a good thing, and, of course, they are the thing I'm currently using. Also, overall performance is only one of the two concerns I have, the other is not blocking the entire application for a long time. In the context I need this, blocking the entire application for a millisecond is almost a bug (the context is a bit complicated, so I won't elaborate). As I see it now, I can either go for performance (vector/unordered_map) or for guaranteed low blocking time (linked list). My question is if I can get both...

Answer (score 0):

There are two obvious solutions: `reserve` enough space before you start, or copy-modify-swap.

Both have significant downsides.  If you don't `reserve` enough, you end up having to occasionally block everything to re-`reserve`.  And copy-modify-swap is overkill usually.

So do both.

Keep track of when you will need a reallocation.  When you don't need a reallocation, simply lock and write.

When you will need a reallocation, copy, reallocate, store, then lock&swap in.

Now things get tricky here.  If two threads try to store we want the second to block.  So we require a two layer system, where writing threads block on the copy-swap if it is happening, and reading threads only block on the lock&swap-back.

```
boost::shared_lock myLock;
boost::lock lock2;
std::unordered_map myMap;

...

myLock.lock_shared();
//try looking up key
myLock.unlock_shared();
if(!success) {
  lock2.lock(); -- write-exclusive
  if (we have room to add another value) {
    myLock.lock(); -- block-readers
    myMap[key] = value;
    myLock.unlock(); // allow readers back in, time is one write with no realloc
  } else {
    auto myCopy = myMap; // ouch
    myCopy.reserve( 50% more memory, or 2x as much memory, or whatever );
    myCopy[key] = value;
    myLock.lock(); // -- block readers
    using std::swap;
    swap( myCopy, myMap );
    myLock.unlock(); // allow readers back in, time is 1 swap!         
  }
  lock2.unlock();
}
```

a downside to this is that other writers can have to wait a long time to write if we are doing a realloc.

If you have only one writer thread, `lock2` need not exist.